# Why is this true? $L\left[\int_{a}^{b}G(x,s)g(s) ds\right] = \int_{a}^{b}L[G(x,s)]g(s) ds?$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I'm learning how Green's functions are used to solve second order inhomogeneous ODEs.

If $$L[y] = a_2(x)y'' + a_1(x)y' + a_0(x)y,$$ how come $$L\left[\int_{a}^{b}G(x,s)g(s) ds\right] = \int_{a}^{b}L[G(x,s)]g(s) ds?$$

I understand why this is the case if $G(x,s) = f(x)q(s)$, but struggle to convince myself when this isn't the case. Is there any good way of thinking about this?

Comment: I know Green' function for PDE's i higher Dimension . But please can tell mwe what mean by Green's function for ODE's?

Comment: Roughly speaking, an integral is a sum, and your operator $L$ is *linear*. That's the key property.

Comment: Basically you want know why does the L switch with the sum right?

Comment: I want to know why you can take $L$ inside the integral.

Comment: I think you should  give the constraints on $a_i$ we can therefore use the continuation argument